# On changing MAC address , I am not able to use the internet or network disconnected

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 17.04, 17.10

On changing MAC address using terminal , the network connection of my PC disconnects . 
The command I used ::

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
sudo macchanger -r wlp3s0
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up
sudo service network-manager start
```

After this : I check my Mac add... Using

```
sudo macchanger -s wlps0
```

Then I got the same Mac address

Comment: I would be nice if you had shown us the _results_, error messages and all, of these commands, plus the result of `sudo lshw -C network`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, "I am not able to use the internet or network disconnected". Ethernet packets (which contain TCP/IP packets), are interchanged on the local LAN, and addressed by MAC address.

So, everybody on your LAN (your router, and other computers connected to it) knows that TCP/IP packets destined for 192.168.0.11 (your IP address) really go to Ethernet address (MAC address) `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`. This was set up by `DHCP`.

Suddenly, you run `sudo macchanger --random`, and your NIC is told to accept only packets destined for Ethernet address (MAC address) `af:be:cd:da:eb:fe`, and use `af:be:cd:da:eb:fe` as its return address.

Ethernet packets destined for `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` are not accepted by your NIC.

Ethernet packets from `af:be:cd:da:eb:fe` have no IP address associated, which isn't good.

Local Lan (wired connection) uses 48-bit Ethernet (MAC) addresses.
Beyond the local LAN (through the router and out the DSL, or whatever) IP addresses are used.